# Process for release management

Tags: stored-procedures, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, release-management

I have 4 jr Developers.

I have one solution over VSTS (git) repository. We use Visual Studio 2015 professional and Azure SQL as database.
We host this application over Azure app service. We publish code with publishsetting file.

Many times I need to look into their conflicts resolving.
Is there any way so that I can handle following scenarios

1) two Developers working on same page. Conflicts occurs. Anyway to avoid (if possible)

2) Some time single developer work on two modules. And one module we need to release to production.
   But one module is still not completed. So we need to publish only completed one. How can we manage this?

3) We have some stored procedures on DEV database. Everytime we need to replicate these changes to QA/UAT then PROD.
   Is there any fine process where we can manage these changes seamlessly.

4) Few changes from team need to go at UAT but not all. It is not good practise to comment the code which not required and Publish.
   Again uncomment after publish and start working.

Can anyone suggest proper streamline process for these scenarios.

Comment: I think your question is too broad but it will boil down to developing a branching/merging strategy. My $.02 is 1) no, but you can mitigate conflicts by avoiding long-running dev work and  merging often 2) merge only those changes that are ready into release branch 3) SSDT database projects built from appropriate branch and published to target environments as needed 4) publish all to UAT but test only those needed (facilitates automation and avoids work customizing for each UAT deployment).

Comment: @Dan Thanks for comment Any tool for automation

Comment: VSTS Release Management comes to mind ;).

Comment: @Kunal, see this for more information on [Azure VSTS RM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/archive/release/previous-version/deploy-continuously-to-azure) jessehouwing mentioned.

Comment: Not clear about the fourth requirement. On the other hand, a question/issue for a thread is better.

Comment: Do you clear it?

Comment: How to publish selective commits or features. I have 4 modules. all completed but I need to publish only 2 modules. How? Note: These 4 modules are on same branch.

Comment: I am afraid that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1:

As far as I know it is impossible, there will be conflicts if others submit a newer version before you submit changes.

Point 2:

Using branch to do it: Create two branches for each modules and merge necessary changes to parent branch for deployment.

Point 3:

Create a release definition with multiple environments and PROD environment is triggered after QA/UAT environment.